# How to get a simple return without same output double (for a Cypher query)?

Tags: neo4j, output, cypher, resultset, simplify

I currently get this as an undesired result from my query:

[image: Undesired result]

I am looking for a query that delivers this result:

[image: Desired result]

I use this query, which delivers me the undesired result:

```
MATCH q = (r:Representative {name: "Graaf"})-[job:FACILITATED]->(b)-[x: jaar_sinds_registratie_coördinator]->(a)
WHERE a.year < 13 AND NOT b:VuurpijlMatch
WITH DISTINCT count(labels(b)) AS countlabel1, labels(b) as labelname1
WITH DISTINCT labelname1, countlabel1

MATCH q = (r:Representative {name: "Graaf"})-[job:FACILITATED]->(b)-[x: jaar_sinds_registratie_coördinator]->(a)
WHERE a.year > 24 AND NOT b:VuurpijlMatch
WITH DISTINCT count(labels(b)) AS countlabel2, labels(b) as labelname2, countlabel1
RETURN DISTINCT labelname2, countlabel2, countlabel1
```

Can anyone provide me an answer / show me what I overlook in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this aggregation operation `WITH DISTINCT count(labels(b)) AS countlabel2, labels(b) as labelname2, countlabel1`. When you do this `countlabel2` is calculated for each distinct combination of `labelname2` and `countlabel1`. That's why you get duplicate records. For reference, your `countlabel2` is calculated for the following combinations:

```
labelname2    countlabel1

NetworkMatch  136
NetworkMatch  5
SettledMatch  136
SettledMatch  5
```

This can be fixed by also fetching labelname1 in the `WITH` so that your combinations for aggregations become this:

```
labelname2    labelname1    countlabel1

NetworkMatch  NetworkMatch  136
NetworkMatch  SettledMatch  5
SettledMatch  NetworkMatch  136
SettledMatch  SettledMatch  5
```

After this, we can simply return the rows, where `labelname1` is equal to `labelname2`.
So your query now becomes something like this:

```
MATCH q = (r:Representative {name: "Graaf"})-[job:FACILITATED]->(b)-[x: jaar_sinds_registratie_coördinator]->(a)
WHERE a.year < 13 AND NOT b:VuurpijlMatch
WITH DISTINCT count(labels(b)) AS countlabel1, labels(b) as labelname1
WITH DISTINCT labelname1, countlabel1

MATCH q = (r:Representative {name: "Graaf"})-[job:FACILITATED]->(b)-[x: jaar_sinds_registratie_coördinator]->(a)
WHERE a.year > 24 AND NOT b:VuurpijlMatch
WITH DISTINCT count(labels(b)) AS countlabel2, labels(b) as labelname2, countlabel1, labelname1
WITH labelname2, countlabel2, countlabel1 WHERE labelname2 = labelname1
RETURN labelname2, countlabel2, countlabel1
```